# Log HTTP request and response executed by a 3rd party NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, exact-online

I use a API client NuGet package that sends HTTP requests and receives responses from a third party API. How can I capture and log the HTTP requests and responses executed by that NuGet package in order to store them in a log database?

Example:

```
var client = new ThirdPartyPackage.Client();
var todos = client.fetchTodos(); // how to log the HTTP request/response executed by the third party package?
```

Specific example: https://github.com/exactonline/exactonline-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/test/ExactOnline.Client.Sdk.IntegrationTests/ExactOnlineQueryTests.cs#L21

Comment: Please provide a sample code for sending requests using this package

Comment: I'm guessing that completely depends on your API/package. And as Ibrahim already mentioned, a [mcve] would be a good idea in this case.

Comment: How does it depend on the API/package? I can't change the code in the NuGet package so I was asking if it's possible to wrap code around it that captures the HTTP traffic.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the API for the package to know what's possible with the existing api, so please post a link to the package or its documentation.

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this? Is it just for debugging purposes or does your app depend on this information for some other reason?

Comment: @IanNewson https://github.com/exactonline/exactonline-api-dotnet-client We would like to store the requests and responses in order to know if something went wrong in our code our with the third party when there are issues in the future.

Comment: You might want to contact the developer of the API directly. When you have an Exact Online subscription call them. Or use wireshark with some tweaking for HTTPS. As an alternative, use our SQL driver such as Invantive Query Tool for Exact Online and after the query run: select * from sessionios.

Answer (score -1):

IIS already does the logging for you. You can find the logs in the folder:%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

You can customize the log schema as you wish. you dont need a Nuget package for this. Or if you want, you can use Nlog

Comment: The API is third party, chances are the poster doesn't have access to the server or its log files.

Answer (score -1):

The library you're using appears to use `WebRequest` under the hood to perform its HTTP requests. Therefore, you should be able to set the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` property to intercept the requests.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

(Source code ref: https://github.com/exactonline/exactonline-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/ExactOnline.Client.Sdk/Helpers/ApiConnector.cs#L167)

Be warned however this is potentially a lot of work depending on exactly how much information you wish to capture about the request, so if I were you I'd seriously consider forking the library and making changes to their code to provide some hooks for logging.

The benefits of the `DefaultWebProxy` approach are that once it's up and working it shouldn't need much maintenance, the negatives are that it's potentially a lot of work up front and is adding another failure point. The benefits of forking the library are that it should be quicker to implement initially, but potentially more ongoing maintenance as you may need to merge any changes to the original SDK manually into your fork. Given that the package you're using has barely changed in 2 years however this seems like an acceptable risk.

In addition, if you go the fork route then you can always send the original repository maintainers a pull request, which would hopefully mean your code eventually ends up in the Nuget package and you can then revert back to Nuget instead of your fork.